# Python Pyserial auto detect com ports

Tags: python-3.x, windows, pyserial

I'm trying to connect to my old switch D-link 1210 to serial port (console) by python3. First script must find COM-port:

```
import serial
import serial.tools.list_ports

print ('Search ports...')
ports = list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())

for p in ports:
    print ('-- Find ports --')
    print (p)
```

Then the script needs to connect to the found port automatically, open port, and send commands.

I don't understand how do this :( Can you help me?
PS sorry for my english

Answer (score 1):

My solution for Python 3.6

```
import os
import sys
import time
import serial
import serial.tools.list_ports

print('Search...')
ports = serial.tools.list_ports.comports(include_links=False)
for port in ports :
    print('Find port '+ port.device)

ser = serial.Serial(port.device)
if ser.isOpen():
    ser.close()

ser = serial.Serial(port.device, 9600, timeout=1)
ser.flushInput()
ser.flushOutput()
print('Connect ' + ser.name)
```

Comment: @ Nesty - Quite like the soln, however -- does this not rely on the very last port in the list 'ports' *i.e. ports[len(ports)-1]* being available for the device you wish to connect. I'm guessing this corresponds to the last port connection - whilst this may have been the case during testing / experimentation with code, wouldn't necessarily be the case in 'live' / actual situations.  In such cases, "ser=serial.Serial(port.device)" followed by "ser.isOpen()/close() may disconnect some other device connection/com port, and then create 2 comm ports for the same device (if that's even possible)?